# How to validate null date values in zf2

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework2

I have a dataset that includes a date field.  In the database, the field defaults to 0000-00-00 when a new row is added.  In my fieldset, the element is defined as follows:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'memberBirthDate',
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Date',
    'attributes' => array(
        'type'  => 'date',
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'birth date',
        'format' => 'n/j/y'
    ),
));
```

I don’t want the element to be required in order for the form to validate.  However, if a date is not inputted, form validation gives the error `The input does not appear to be a valid date`.

Also, the format `'n/j/y'` renders the null value as `11/30/-1`.  If `0` is entered in the input, form validation gives the error `The input does not appear to be a valid date` and if something like `0/0/00` is entered, validation gives both `The input does not appear to be a valid date` and `The input does not fit the date format 'n/j/y'`.

Is there a way to get the validator to accept a null date value or to skip validation for inputs that are not changed?

### EDIT

`allow_empty` doesn’t work.  I’ve set it and also set `'required' -> false`.  I even checked to make sure that the validation attributes were being passed all of the way to the controller and the view by echoing all of the errors and attributes.  The following code:

```
// enumerate message
$messages = $form->getMessages();
if($messages) {
  echo "<h4>error messages:</h4>";
  print_r ($messages);
}
echo "<br/>";
echo "allow_empty: " . $memberBirthDate->getAttribute('allow_empty') . "<br/>";
echo "required: " . $memberBirthDate->getAttribute('required') . "<br/>";
```

produces:

```
Array ( [member-fieldset] => Array ( [memberBirthDate] => Array ( [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty ) ) ) 
allow_empty: 1
required:
```

### EDIT 2

I do have a filter specified in the fieldset.  This part of my project follows the format presented http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html, which doesn’t suggest anything about using a factory.  My filters are like this:

```
namespace AdminMembers\Form;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

use AdminMembers\Entity\Member;

class MemberFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('member-fieldset');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'AdminMembers\Entity\Member'))
             ->setObject(new Member());

            // ...

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'memberBirthDate',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Date',
                'required' => false,
                'allow_empty' => true,
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'date',
                'required' => false,
                'allow_empty' => true,
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'birth date',
                'format' => 'n/j/y'
            ),
        ));

            // ...

    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {

            // ...

        return array(
            'memberBirthDate' => array(
                'required' => false,
                'allow_empty' => true,
            ),
        );

            // ...

    }

}
```

and

```
namespace AdminMembers\Form;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class AddMemberForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('add_member_form');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'AdminMembers\Entity\Member'));

        $adminMemberFieldset = new MemberFieldset($objectManager);
        $adminMemberFieldset->setUseAsBaseFieldset(true);
        $this->add($adminMemberFieldset);

        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setInputFilter(new InputFilter());

          // ...

        $this->setValidationGroup(array(
            'member-fieldset' => array(
                'memberID',
                    // ...
                'memberBirthDate',
                    // ...
            ),
        ));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a filter to it.

Example Filter:

```
namespace YourNamespace\Filter;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

class YourFilter extends InputFilter
{
    public function getInputFilter()
    {
        $this->add(
            array(
                'name' => 'memberBirthDate',
                'required' => true,
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Example Factory:

```
namespace YourNamespace\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;

class YourFactory extends FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {  
        $form = new \YourNamespace\Form\YourForm();

        $filter = new \YourNamespace\Filter\YourFilter();

        $form->setInputFilter($filter->getInputFilter());

        return $form;
    }
}
```

registrate factory on servicemanager key at module.config.php:
you should probably merge with older configurations:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'YourNamespace\Factory\YourFactoryFinalName' => 'YourNamespace\Factory\YourFactory'
    ),
)
```

call anywhere service manager is avaiable, the form with filter witch you can add more filters rules by your own.

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('YourNamespace\Factory\YourFactoryFinalName');
```

extra: create get/set to use anywhere when you need this factory easily by traits:

```
namespace YourNamespace\Factory;

use YourNamespace\Factory\YourFactory

trait YourFactoryTrait {

    protected $yourFactory;

    public function getYourFactory()
    {
        if (!isset($this->yourFactory)) {
            $this->yourFactory = this->getServiceLocator()->get('YourNamespace\Factory\YourFactoryFinalName');
        }
        return $this->yourFactory;
    }

    public function setYourFactory(YourFactory $yourFactory)
    {
        $this->yourFactory = $yourFactory;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

the attributes of a class that you intend to use:

```
use YourNamespace\Factory\YourFactoryTrait;
```

in the method body:

```
$factory = $this->getYourFactory();
$factory->setData($data);

if ($factory->isValid()) {
}
```

Comment: I do have a filter specified.  See EDIT 2.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure a field to allow empty values through the input filter. Take a look at this article by Rob Allen (akrabat) on `allow_empty` here: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/setting-up-required-fields-that-can-be-empty-with-zendinputfilter/

Comment: Are you putting it on the element's input filter?  It won't work if you put it on the element itself